# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () | Oracle & ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core-mvc, named-pipes, http-status-code-500

I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I have migrated my ASP.NET Framework project to ASP.NET Core, and when I launch the project, I get these kinds of errors :

> This page isn't working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**Startup.cs** :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [...]
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Web:ConnectionString")));
    [...]
}
```

**appsettings.json** :

```json
[...]
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Web": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.X.XXX)(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXX)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;",
    "ProviderName": "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
  }
}
[...]
```

**DataAccessLayer.cs** :

```cs
public class DataAccessLayer : IDisposable
{
  private IDatabase _core = null;
  
  public void Dispose() { _core?.Dispose(); }

  public DataAccessLayer() { _core = Load(); }

  private static Database Load()
  {
    // Get Instance of Configuration with appsettings.json
    IConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cfgBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    IConfiguration cfg = cfgBuilder.Build();

    var connectionString = cfg["ConnectionStrings:Web:ConnectionString"];
    var provider = cfg["ConnectionStrings:Web:ProviderName"];
    if (provider != "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client") {
      return null;
    }
    return new Database(connectionString, DatabaseType.OracleManaged, SqlClientFactory.Instance);
  }
  public Client GetClient(string idWorkflow)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idWorkflow)) {
      try {
        return _core.FirstOrDefault<Client>(Sql.Builder.Where("ID_WORKFLOW=@0", idWorkflow));
      }
      catch (Exception) {
        return new Client();
      }
    }
    else {
      return new Client();
    }
  }
  [...]
}
```

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Whether Oracle's service is turned on? And Oracle may have expired, or it may be internet problem, can you use `ping` to connect to oracle?

Comment: Yes, I can ping Oracle actually... So...

Comment: What is the version of ef core? Try this ConnectionString: `Data Source=*.*.*.*;database=dbname;User ID=[username];Password=[password];port=1521`

Comment: @Karney. Same error with this ConnectionString... I use Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 3.19.80 & NPoco 4.0.2

Comment: Do you have any errors in migration file when migrating database (not migrating from ASP.NET Framework project to ASP.NET Core)?

Comment: @Karney. No I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the return of your Load() with this one :

```
return new Database(connectionString, DatabaseType.OracleManaged, new OracleClientFactory());
```

It will surely work better ^^